# Grep file with keyword in particular date (UNIX)

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I would like to grep/searc a list of files which containing some keyword within a particular date.

An example is:

> grep file which contain 'keyword' AND the file modified date is on 'Jun 1'

My code is:

```
ls |grep 'keyword' *.txt
```

And

```
ls -ltr|grep 'Jun 1'
```

How am i going to combine this two together?

Comment: What version of `find` are you using. Can you output `find --version`?

Comment: @Inian He does not know about `find`. That is the reason why he parses `ls`. Maybe he should read this: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this:

```
ls|grep 'keyword' *.txt|cut -d ':' -f1|xargs ls -ltr|grep 'Jun 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like

```
find /directory -type f -mtime -10 -mtime +5 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l expression
```

Here, `/directory` is the dir you want to search in, `-mtime` specifies the time range, then piping with `xargs` you can combine the second search for grep to find in the files.